# Add a list element in yaml with a comment on top of it

Tags: python-3.x, ruamel.yaml

I have a yaml file consisting of a list that has the following structure:

```
# Comment for item one
- key1: item1
  key2: item1
# Comment for item two
- key1: item2
  key2: item2
# Comment for item seven
- key1: item7
  key2: item7
```

Is it possible to add another list entry with ruamel.yaml or a different library with a corresponding comment? Also is it possible to add this entry somewhere in the middle or top (based on alphabetical sorting in my case)?

Example result when adding `{key1: item5, key2: item5}` to the list:

```
# Comment for item one
- key1: item1
  key2: item1
# Comment for item two
- key1: item2
  key2: item2
# Comment for item five
- key1: item5
  key2: item5
# Comment for item seven
- key1: item7
  key2: item7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, please realise that `ruamel.yaml` was primarily made to preserve
comments (and anchors, aliases, tags), while updating values
in YAML files. For that it creates special data structures on which
it then attaches the necessary information. You can use
these routines and datastructures, but they are not a published, will change,
and where/how the extra data is attached might be counterintuitive.

Comments, are usually attached to the preceding node. That is mostly appropriate
for end-of-line comments. Empty lines or full line comments are extensions of
the preceding end-of-line comments (even if the end of line comments are empty).

So the comment that reads "# Comment for item two" is associated with
the `key2` of the `key2: item1` key-value pair of the first element of the root level sequence in
your YAML document. You can see this by printing the `.ca` (comment attribute) of
the relevant collection (`dict` in this case):

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
# Comment for item one
- key1: item1
  key2: item1
# Comment for item two
- key1: item2
  key2: item2
# Comment for item seven
- key1: item7
  key2: item7
"""
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
print(data[0].ca)
```

which gives:

```
Comment(comment=None,
  items={'key2': [None, None, CommentToken('\n# Comment for item two\n', line: 3, col: 0), None]})
```

As you can see the comment itself starts with a newline: that is the empty EOL comment after `key2: item1`

So you'll need to keep track of where you insert the new dictionary and do
some copying/moving of comments. The code for this can be made more
generic, but for now I'll assume a root level sequence with mappings as elements:

```py
value = 'item5'
dict_to_add = dict(key1=value, key2=value)  
position = 2                               

mark = ruamel.yaml.error.CommentMark(0)  # the actual column is irrelevant

elem = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap(dict_to_add)
data.insert(position, elem)
preceding_dict = data[position - 1]
last_key_of_pd = list(preceding_dict.keys())[-1]
comment_token = data[position - 1].ca.items[last_key_of_pd][2]
data[position].ca.items[list(dict_to_add.keys())[-1]] = [None, None, comment_token, None]
data[position - 1].ca.items[last_key_of_pd][2] = ruamel.yaml.tokens.CommentToken('\n# Comment for item five', mark, None)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

giving:

```
# Comment for item one
- key1: item1
  key2: item1
# Comment for item two
- key1: item2
  key2: item2
# Comment for item five
- key1: item5
  key2: item5
# Comment for item seven
- key1: item7
  key2: item7
```

Comment: Comments, are usually attached to the preceding node - This is what gave most clarity. Seems like remaking the structure into same-line comments will help me out in the future. Thanks!