RUAMEL.YAML in Python adding extra line between new list entry
I'm using ruamel.yaml 0.18.6 and Python 3.9.x.
I am trying to amend certain objects of data within my yaml file.  I load my yaml file, which has a mix of comments and various yaml constructs, add the list entries I need to the Python object(s) of these Yaml data structures and then write them out.  However, every time I add a new 'list' item, ruamel adds an empty 'line' between the last list entry and my new one.
For example, here is an example yaml file:
name: someone

age: 100

# this is a comment
# and another

block1:
  - aaa
  - bbb

block2:
    sub:
      - 111
      - 222
      # a comment
      - 333

I'm loading the file with:
from ruamel.yaml import Yaml

def loader(my_yaml_file):
  yaml = Yaml()
  with open(my_yaml_file, "r", encoding="UTF-8") as file:
    return yaml.load(file)

def writer(data, my_yaml_file):
  yaml = Yaml()
  yaml.indent(mapping=2, seuqence=4, offset=2)
  with open(my_yaml_file, "w", encoding="UTF-8") as file:
    yaml.dump(data, file)

def do_stuff():
  my_yaml_file = "file.yml"
  loaded_yaml = loader(my_yaml_file)
  loaded_yaml["block1"].append("ccc")
  writer(loaded_yaml, my_yaml_file)

When I run my code, my written/updated yaml looks like this:
name: someone

age: 100

# this is a comment
# and another

block1:
  - aaa
  - bbb

  - ccc
block2:
    sub:
      - 111
      - 222
      # a comment
      - 333

Ideally, I'd like it to look like this:
name: someone

age: 100

# this is a comment
# and another

block1:
  - aaa
  - bbb
  - ccc

block2:
    sub:
      - 111
      - 222
      # a comment
      - 333

There is always a new line between - bbb and - ccc in the block1 module.  I can't figure out why.  I've tried various settings and suggestions from the documentation but nothing works.  It either stays like this, or I can write it out but all the comments vanish.  And sadly, I have to keep the comments in the file as they are a requirement.
When I debug, I can see this CommentToken('\n\n') mentioned in the ca section of the module, so it believes that last line is a comment...?  Yet on other structures, when it gets written out (such as block2) it writes it out fine.
Anyone with any suggestions?

You cannot import Yaml from ruamel.yaml. What is new as in yaml = new Yaml() supposed to do? Please provide code that will run when copy/pasted. UTF-8  files are binary files, you should open them as rb/wb or better just supply a pathlib.Path() instance to yaml.load()/yaml.dump(). Comments are normally attached to the last node parsed, so it is to be expected that the empty line is preserved after - bbb. You will have to move the comment, if you want it after - ccc.

Agh, sorry @Anthon - please check again!  I have ti use my mobile to type it all out as we're not allowed to use SO from a work machine..  go figure.  And i foolishly mixed some old Java syntax in!  Apologies.

But what is it considering to be the last comment?  in
block1, I havent used a comment.  But in block2 I did simply to show that it does work fine on that 'unaltered' section of the yaml.  It's just when I manipulate a list it seems to add that space between the last list antry and whatever new one i add. Sorry if i confused you

Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76075134/add-a-list-element-in-yaml-with-a-comment-on-top-of-it/76075943#76075943 if that doesn't work out for you let me know.

an empty line is considered to be an empy EOL comment followed by a newline. It gets attached to the node - ddd, you should be able to find it using print(loaded_yaml['block1'].ca). You will have to update the entries (IIRC) attribute of that after appending the element (i.e. move the comment from element 2 to 3 in this case)

that should be node - bbb
